# How can I access a select in an HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I added a select to a column of table cells with an ID. Using console.log I can see the select with the ID I gave it but when I try to set the value of the box using the ID I get a NULL reference error. What would the correct reference be for the box? Thanks.

**JavaScript**

```
function GetProc_Responce(r, responce) {
  var table = "<tr><th>Emp</th><th>RA</th><th>PI</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Is A</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Date Modified</th></tr>";
  strXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(responce);

  //console.log("returnString: " + strXml);
  var oParser = new DOMParser();
  oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(strXml, "text/xml");

  //console.log(oDOM.getElementsByTagName("EmployeeID").length);
  var l = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("EmployeeID").length;
  for (i = 0; i <= l - 1; i++) {
    a = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("Emp")[i];
    _Emp = a.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    b = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("RA")[i];
    _RA = b.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    c = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("PI")[i];
    _PI = c.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    d = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("FirstName")[i];
    _FirstName = d.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    e = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("LastName")[i];
    _LastName = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    f = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("IsA")[i];
    _IsA = f.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    g = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("DateCreated")[i];
    _DateCreated = g.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    h = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("DateModified")[i];
    _DateModified = h.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "<tr><td>" +
      a.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      b.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      c.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      d.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      e.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      //f.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      "<select id=\"s1\"><option value=\"0\">0</option><option value=\"1\">1</option></select>" + "</td><td>" +
      g.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      h.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";

    document.getElementById('Proc').rows.item(3).cells(5).value = 1;
    //OR
    document.getElementById('s1').selectedValue = 1;
    //NEITHER ONE WORKS


  }
  document.getElementById("Proc").innerHTML = table;

  console.log(document.getElementById('Proc').rows(3).cells(5));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><center>
  <table id="Proc"></table>
</center></div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "combobox" in HTML... you might want to clarify that?!

Comment: @Tinman it's not 'combobox', it's a select

Comment: Select dropdown acts as a combobox. Sorry for the incorrect reference. I've been working in VB lately.

Comment: No, a combobox is a widget that allows you to enter text ***or*** select a value (that's why it is called that way: combination of the two).

Comment: @Tinman let's put the correct name, just to clarify for people who search for this in the future

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('s1').value = "1";` IDs are supposed to be unique, so use different ones in each cell

Comment: That wont work either. I believe it's the reference to "s1" that it cant see. Although the  console.log(document.getElementById('Proc').rows(3).cells(5)); does show the ID as "s1". That's where I'm stumped.

Comment: You won't be able to access the elements you're adding until you added them to the DOM, which happens in the `document.getElementById("Proc").innerHTML = table;` call.

Comment: Ahh! Cells dont have a `value` member, though they do have an `innerHTML` and an `innerText` one. As for the select element, it has a `value` member, not a `selectedValue`

Answer (score 2):

You must assign unique *id* values. Your code assigns all of them the *id* value `s1` which is invalid in HTML.

Change your code as follows to assign `s0`, `s1`, `s2` ... etc. For clarity I don't repeat the code that is not concerned:

```
for (i = 0; i <= l - 1; i++)
{
    // ...
    table += "<tr><td>" +
            // ...
            e.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
            "<select id=\"s" + i + "\"><option value=\"0\">0</option><option value=\"1\">1</option></select>" + "</td><td>" +
            // ...
 }
```

You can access one of the `select` elements by its *id* with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
var element = document.getElementById('s' + i);
```

Where *i* is a number from `0` to the last one assigned in the loop.

You can get or set the value of a `select` element via its `value` attribute. For example, to set its value to 1, do:

```
document.getElementById('s' + i).value = '1';
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. I thought I could reference it from the cell but it makes more sense to just increment the ID. But that makes it hard to set the values as they are being populated sine it is not available until the entire table is displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here we'll get div object

```
var div     = document.getElementById('test');
```

Here we'll get table object

```
var table = div.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

Here we'll add new select to td

```
table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML += '<select id="s2"></select>';
```

Search existed select (with id="s1")

```
var select_1 = table.rows[0].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
console.log(select_1);
```

Search all selects in td

```
var select_array = table.rows[0].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('select');
console.log(select_array);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e59dzhsy/

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Although the code might be valid and solve an issue, please still edit your question and add some explanation of your code and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('Proc').rows.item(3).cells(5)` references a td, which does not have a value.

`document.getElementById('s1')` references the select box

you want `document.getElementById('Proc').rows.item(3).cells(5).children[0]` to reference the select

A better method would be to use some of the built in tag finding functions such as `document.getElementById('Proc').rows[3].getElementsByTagName('select')[0]`.  Then you don't have to deal with what column the select is in.  Of course, if you have more than one select on the row, then you'll need to do something different.  At that point, I'd suggest adding class names to your selects so you can use `document.getElementById('Proc').rows[3].getElementsByClassName('select1')[0]`